# Way to know which user moved the letter to the folder

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

Dovecot 2.2 + Postfix 2.1
Public folder namespace:

> location = maildir:/domain/public:CONTROL=~/Maildir/control/public:INDEX=~/Maildir/index/public

I have a public folder "sales" for group of users. All messages that are sent to sales@domain.com fall into this directory. Sometimes users moves letters to another folder. Then CRM system checks these letters.

I need to understand witch user moved the letter to the folder. 
Is there any way to get this information, or mark a letters header?
Dovecot debug mode does not give such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot's logging will not really help you with this, unless you enable [rawlog](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Debugging/Rawlog), but I don't think parsing IMAP sessions is a good thing to do.

Have a look at [Dovecot's plugins](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins): there are several ways that might help you building some kind of notification system.

- The [Mail Logger plugin](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/MailLog) can (among other things) can log copy operations (move operations are likely to be implemented as copy and delete) and will log lines like

  ```
  imap(user): copy -> Trash: uid=908, msgid=<123.foo@bar>
  ```

  You can even limit logging to the specific operations you're looking for. Observe this log with some kind of daemon that triggers upon specific log lines.
- Use the [notify API](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/Notify) to implement your own plugin, which directly triggers from within Dovecot.